# How to create scrollable UITabBarController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to show 10 views on `UITabBar` with scrolling functionality. For this I am using `UITabBar` on a `UIScrollView`. But I am not able to show different different views after click on a item of `UITabBar`. So please suggest that how to add `UIViewController` on `UITabBar` items.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following Custom scrollable `UITabBar` sample code link,

https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar

Hope it will satisfy your needs.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this github repository which creates scrollable tabbar [Custom Scrollable Tabbar](https://github.com/jain-mohit/CustomTabBar)

Hope it helps you.